# sqlserver connection through groovy script

Tags: groovy

I want to make sql connection with windows authentication through sqlserverjdbc jar in SoapUI using groovy. Can anyone help me out, I'm getting an error  -

source code -

```
import sqlserverjdbc.*;
def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:sqlserver://servername/databasename","integratedSecurity=true","com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
```

Error -
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Sql for class: Script7 error at line:2

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the driver is on the classpath, you just need to

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
```

Comment: Still getting an error - java.sql.SqlException: No suitable Driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://servername/databasename
Whereas classpath having the path of the sqlserverjdbc.jar

Comment: Yeah, that's because the driver isn't on the classpath (see the first assumption in my answer)